# Ansible Inventory: how to build a group from hosts not in certain other groups

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am looking for a way to build an inventory group that includes all those hosts that haven't been put into another group.

In my case, the groups identify when a particular server should be updated - either on Mondays, Wednesdays, Fridays, or "any day, it doesn't matter". I do not want to explicitly enumerate the hosts, as that is manual work and error-prone.

```
all:
  hosts:
    host1[1-100].example.com:
  children:
    updateMonday:
      hosts:
        host1.example.com:
        host4.example.com:
    updateWednesday:
      hosts:
        host2.example.com:
        host5.example.com:
    updateFriday:
      hosts:
        host3.example.com:
        host6.example.com:
    updateAnyday:
      children:
        # This expresses what I want but does not work
        !updateMonday:
        !updateWednesday:
        !updateFriday:
```

I am using additional groups not shown in this example, so I can't simply use the "ungrouped" group to do what I want.

Edit: I do not want to modify the playbooks I use, because I have quite a few of them, and I also need ad-hoc commands to honor the new group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a group with all hosts, e.g. *updateAll*

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    host[1-100].example.com:
  children:
    updateAll:
      hosts:
        host[1-100].example.com:
    updateMonday:
      hosts:
        host1.example.com:
        host4.example.com:
  ...
```

In the first play create dynamically the group *updateAnyday* and use it in the second play

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups: updateAnyday
      loop: "{{ groups.updateAll|
                difference(groups.updateMonday)|
                difference(groups.updateWednesday)|
                difference(groups.updateFriday) }}"
      run_once: true

- hosts: updateAnyday
  tasks:
  ...
```

<sup>(Not tested)</sup>

---

Q: *"**I don't want to modify the playbook.**"*

A: Create a file with the list of the hosts *updateAnyday.txt*, e.g. use the playbook above. Then run your playbook *updateAnyday.yml* with limited inventory, e.g.

```sh
shell> ansible-playbook updateAnyday.yml --limit @updateAnyday.txt
```

See [Patterns and ansible-playbook flags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#patterns-and-ansible-playbook-flags).

Comment: Interesting idea, thank you! I forgot to mention in the question that I don't want to modify the playbook. But the answer itself is excellent.

Comment: You're welcome! The next option might be to create a file with a limited list of the hosts.

Comment: I didn't realize that --limit can accept a file. That may actually solve several other problems I have, too!

Comment: Just for those who may find this through Google: After experimenting with this a bit, I discovered a limitation of the first approach: since the group is only created dynamically, I cannot specify it with the --limit command line option. It also will not work (obviously) with ad-hoc commands. The second version should solve both problems, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a play and change the host with the group combinations. For instance, all the hosts except the updateMonday, updateWednesday, and updateFriday would be:

```yaml
hosts: all:!updateMonday:!updateWednesday:!updateFriday
```

You can also dynamically create the group using `add_host` or `group_by` commands.